# jQuery not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a dynamic menu by reading an XML file using jQuery. I have developed the code, and it works fine in Firefox 3 and Chrome, however it just doesn't work for Internet Explorer 7/8.

I'm posting my code below. What is the matter with it?

```
  var menu ="";
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "menu.xml",
          dataType: "xml",
          success: parseXml
      });
  });

  function parseXml(xml)
  {
      $(xml).find('link').each(function(x){
          var link = $(this);
          var title = link.attr("name");

          menu += "<div class='AccordionPanel AccordionPanelClosed'>";
          menu += "<div class='AccordionPanelTab'><span></span>";
          menu += "<a href='javascript:;'>"+title+"</a></div>";

          link.find("inLink").each(function(z){
              var intitle = $(this).attr("name");
              menu += "<div class='AccordionPanelContent'>";
              menu += "<ul><li>";
              menu += "<a href='"+$(this).attr("ref")+"'>"+intitle+"</a>";
              menu += "</li></ul></div>";
          });
          menu += "</div>";
      });

      $("#LeftMenu").append(menu);
  }
```

The XML file has the following structure

```
  <links>
      <link name="Reception" ref="index.html">
          <inLink name="Registration" ref="registration.html"/>
          <inLink name="Inquiry" ref="#"/>
      </link>
      <link name="Records" ref="#">
          <inLink name="Records" ref="#"/>
          <inLink name="Records2" ref="#"/>
      </link>
  </links>
```

Comment: Maybe post the particular error you get?

Comment: im taking a wild guess, but i bet its cause you have parseXML outisde the scope of the document onready function .. unless IE error happens earlier

Comment: Yeah...where does it fail.  Put alert statements at a bunch of different checkpoints to make sure your code is executing and your objects and references to dom elements aren't null/undefined

Comment: It does nothing...no error message..  the page just loads up and the div "LeftMenu" where the script is supposed to fill in the content remains blank..

Comment: i've tried putting alerts inside the function, even right at the beginning of parseXML function.. but its not called..

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ? ... I know it seems weird but its IE

Comment: actually, after looking at the code, it IS running... but that function isnt getting called so menu ( still just empty quotes "") is getting appended hence the nothing-ness.  Ill bet 200 rep on this

Comment: @theman_on_vista yes I tried that too.. I removed it as a separate function and wrote the code inside the "$(document).ready(function()" block itself.. then too it was the same issue..

Comment: Are you sure your getting XML, or anything, back ?

Comment: The XML is a physical file on the disk..

Comment: its failing somewhere in the AJAX request itself.. i don't know why tho.. :( 
even if i start with some characters in the "menu" variable.. it doesn't show up there.. that means, its not getting to the point where it appends "menu" string to the div.

Comment: danish, riddle me this - how do you HTTP GET something locally?  are you running a webserver on local disk?  javascript cant load stuff off the local disk

Comment: Okay.. I am a certified fool!! :( sorry for all the trouble guys.. @theman_on_vista.. you ROCK.. 
i couldn't believe the level of my stupidity...how could i even overlook it.. 
i got it running through a web server and its now working.. 
im still puzzled as how other browsers got it working.. :S

Comment: lol ya stuff like that always scares me when it magically works in other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
 $("#LeftMenu").append($(menu));
```

it's just a thought though.

Comment: i just looked at your website and OMG i love kitties!!

Comment: hey John, thanks for the help.. but as you might notice.. it was my foolishness at the best in this case.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem parsing an XML AJAX return, it worked fine on FF, but failed on IE.

The problem I had was extra nodes between the nodes that you are expecting. IE adds text nodes with whitespace to the XML DOM where there is whitespace in the XML file.

I fixed it by changing the generated XML so there was no whitespace between nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but try this for your ajax request instead.

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "menu.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){parseXml(xml);}
    });